# Internet Speed Indicator for Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, internet, indicator, download-speed

I'm a new Lubuntu user. All I need is a numeric internet speed indicator to be added on the bottom bar. While using Ubuntu, I used to install an extension to do this task, but what I know is Gnome extensions cannot be installed on Lubuntu, so, are there any alternatives for Lubuntu?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not a `Lubuntu` user but will `NetSpeed` work for you? Scroll down [this resource](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/06/download-upload-speed-ubuntu-20-04-panel/) to the update for 22.04 and give it a try.

Comment: **Lubuntu** uses **LXQt** instead of **GNOME**, so it cannot be installed. I tried btw, and it says unsupported.

Comment: ah well, pity but worth a punt. Thanks for letting me know.